# ore.frame elements connected with label, cannot get rid of the label

Tags: r, database, label

This is issue is using R Oracle library called ORE.
I am trying to use the elements of an ORE.frame (it´s like a data.frame in R) but they are coupled with a label/index that I cannot get rid of.
The ORE.frame I am using is the result of an aggregate function.

This is my ore.frame (named agg) when printed:

```
     Group.1    Group.2   x
a|b    a          b      35
c|d    c          d      12
e|f    e          f      8
```

The ore.frame has 3 rows and 3 columns. The columns are Group.1, Group.2 and x. The first column is generated automatically by the aggregate function and my problem is that I cannot get rid of it when trying to access the elements of the agg ore.frame.

Example:

```
print(agg[1,1])
a|b
  a
```

When I do this loop below, it just doesn't properly access the elements of agg:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(agg)){

  concat=paste(agg[row,1],"..",agg[row,2])
  print(concat)
}
```

It prints:

```
..
..
..
```

Does anybody know how to get rid of the label that is associated with each element of the ore.frame?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```
row.names(agg) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
> employee <- c('Abc','Sakhuja','Electra')
> id <- c(1, 2, 3)
> startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2018-5-26','2018-3-14'))

# Case 1
> employ.data <- data.frame(employee, id, startdate, row.names=paste0("a|d", 1:3))
> employ.data
            employee id  startdate
a|d1             Abc  1 2010-11-01
a|d2         Sakhuja  2 2018-05-26
a|d3         Electra  3 2018-03-14

> row.names(employ.data) <- NULL
> employ.data
  employee id  startdate
1             Abc 1 2010-11-01
2         Sakhuja  2 2018-05-26
3         Electra  3 2018-03-14

# Case 2
> employ.data <- data.frame(employee, id, startdate, row.names=paste0("a|d", 1:3))
> employ.data
     employee id  startdate
a|d1             Abc  1 2010-11-01
a|d2         Sakhuja  2 2018-05-26
a|d3         Electra  3 2018-03-14
>
> print(employ.data, row.names=FALSE)
employee id  startdate
             Abc  1 2010-11-01
         Sakhuja  2 2018-05-26
         Electra  3 2018-03-14
```